# lmfit: best way of adding several constrained parameters

Tags: python, constraints, lmfit

I'd like to describe some experimental data using a model which needs *n* different parameters, which are all mutually constrained according to:

phi<sub>1</sub> + phi<sub>2</sub> + phi<sub>3</sub> + ... + phi<sub>n</sub> = 1

with

phi<sub>i+1</sub> < phi<sub>i</sub>

and

0 < phi<sub>i</sub>  < 1

Building on the suggestion of the lmfit manual on the use of constraints (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/constraints.html), I wrote the following piece of code:

```
fit_params = Parameters()
for i in range(len(Files)):
        filename = Files[i]
        fit_params.add('z_knot0', value = 0.0, vary = False) #position of first knot
        fit_params.add('phi_knot0', value = guessed['phi_knot0'][filename], min=0.1, max=1.0, vary = True) #volume fraction of brush at the brush/substrate interface. 
        for j in range(1,GFP['n_knots']+1):
            fit_params.add('d_knot' + str(j), value = guessed['d_knot'+str(j)][filename], min = 1.0, max = 100.0, vary = True) #spacing between two consecutive knots
            ex = 'd_knot' + str(j) + ' + z_knot' + str(j-1)
            # print(ex)
            fit_params.add('z_knot' + str(j), expr=ex) #z position of jth knot.
    
            fit_params.add('delta_phi_knot' + str(j), value = guessed['delta_phi_knot'+str(j)][filename], min = 0.0, max = 0.5, vary = True) #decrease of polymer volume fraction between two consecutive knots
            ex1 = 'phi_knot' + str(j-1) + '- delta_phi_knot' + str(j) 
            phi_knot = ex1 + ' if ' + ex1 + ' > 0 else 0'
            
            fit_params.add('phi_knot' + str(j), expr=phi_knot)
```

what worries me, is if this part of the code:

```
fit_params.add('delta_phi_knot' + str(j), value = guessed['delta_phi_knot'+str(j)][filename], min = 0.0, max = 0.5, vary = True) #decrease of polymer volume fraction between two consecutive knots
ex1 = 'phi_knot' + str(j-1) + '- delta_phi_knot' + str(j) 
phi_knot = ex1 + ' if ' + ex1 + ' > 0 else 0'
fit_params.add('phi_knot' + str(j), expr=phi_knot)
```

is an issue for the fitting routine (I use the differential evolution method). I am not getting any error, and the constraints seems also to be correctly taken into account when modelling the data. However, the fitting routine does not seem to converge towards a good solution, as I am able to simulate a curve which has a smaller chi^2 value than the one obtained from the fit. This seems to most delicate part of the code where something which I do not understand might take place.

I am grateful for any advice. Thanks,
Leonardo

Answer (score 0):

Skipping over how you set the other parameter values, I would encourage you to think of `phi_n+1 = phi_n + step_n`, with `step_n` having a lower bound of zero.  Perhaps something like this:

```
import lmfit
nknots = 7
params = lmfit.Parameters()

init_step = 2./(nknots*(nknots+1))

params.add('phi0', value=init_step, min=0, max=1)
all_phis = ['phi0']
for i in range(nknots-1): 
    params.add('step%d'%i, value=init_step, min=0, max=1)
    params.add('phi%d'%(i+1), expr='phi%d + step%d'%(i, i), min=0, max=1)
    all_phis.append('phi%d'%i)
    
# expression for final phi so that Sum(phi_N) = 1
params.add('phi%d'%(nknots-1), expr='1-(%s)' % ('+'.join(all_phis)), min=0, max=1)



for p in params.values():
    print(p)
```

Note here that `phi0` and all of the `stepN` parameters will be variables in the fit.  The remaining `phiN` values are constrained by their expressions.

I guess that this does not strictly guarantee that `phiN > phiN-1`, but it should get you started. For that, it may be that making a `stepN` parameter that is constrained somehow might be needed as well....

Comment: Thanks for the answer (and for the hint for improved formatting). And here I apologize that I made a mistake in the question, where indeed the sum of all phi values should be minor or equal to 1.  

What about the if-sentence, is it a danger for the fit? In particular for methods which explore the whole parameter space?

Comment: the `a if condition else b` form is not needed if you place bounds on the values for `step_N` and `phi_N`, and that form runs the risk of giving a discontinuity in the result which will mess up the fit method (which assumes smooth derivates of residual with respect to parameter value).  It is also harder to read.